# how to customize angular-datatables' style

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I'm new to angular, trying to use angular-datatables library http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay, but don't know how to control the style of the table, cause they are all angular directives, is it possible I can touch the HTML elements inside? like the example below, how can I remove the text next to search box? Also I've read API, couldn't find how to hide the datatables_info on the buttom.

[image]

[image]

---

update

maybe I can hide them through CSS, but seems it's impossible to add placeholder to the input element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Search box text**

You can do this in various ways, also by manipulating the injected DOM elements - but the "correct" way would be to alter the [**language**](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html) settings.  The default language object literal is

```js
var lang = {
    "decimal":        "",
    "emptyTable":     "No data available in table",
    "info":           "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
    "infoEmpty":      "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
    "infoFiltered":   "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
    "infoPostFix":    "",
    "thousands":      ",",
    "lengthMenu":     "Show _MENU_ entries",
    "loadingRecords": "Loading...",
    "processing":     "Processing...",
    "search":         "Search:",
    "zeroRecords":    "No matching records found",
    "paginate": {
        "first":      "First",
        "last":       "Last",
        "next":       "Next",
        "previous":   "Previous"
    },
    "aria": {
        "sortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
        "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
    }
}
```

Change `search` to `""` and include `lang` as `language` option :

```js
.withOption('language', lang)
```

> **Hide the datatables_info at the bottom**

You can disable the table information summary completely by omitting the `i` flag from the [**`dom`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option. The default `dom` setting is `lfrtip`, so simply

```js
.withDOM('lfrtp')
```

See both solutions in action here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/3WqPj1IW1h3zK37hF4dv?p=preview**

---

> **add placeholder to the input element**

The injected search box is located at `.dataTables_filter input`. You can use `angular.element()` or `document.querySelector()` to manipulate such DOM elements. To add a placeholder to the search box

```
.withOption('initComplete', function() {
   angular.element('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Search ...');
})
```

> **add ng-bind or ng-click on the 'previous' and 'next' button**

This is very tricky. The injected elements has nothing to do with angular - I believe it *is* somehow possible to add a `ng-click` to an element and then (re)`$compile`. However, the pagination buttons is recreated each and every time the table is redrawn, so the angularification' would need to happen over and over. But you can easily facilitate events for the prev/next buttons without std angular directives :

```
.withOption('drawCallback', function() {
   angular.element('.paginate_button.previous').on('click', function() { alert('prev')} )
   angular.element('.paginate_button.next').on('click', function() { alert('next')} )             
})
```

There is also a `page.dt` event, fired when the active page changes :

```
angular.element('body').on('page.dt', function(e, api) {
   console.log('Page #'+(api._iDisplayStart / api._iDisplayLength + 1) +' shown') ;
})
```

Comment: can I ask another question, how should I manipulate injected DOM elements, for example, if I want to add ng-bind or ng-click on the 'previous' and 'next' button

Comment: This is really useful to me, I'm trying to use this way to add an element inside the table, `angular.element('.previous').after('<a>test</a>');` It's working, but when switching to another table page, the added element disappears. Can I ask what's the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: @VincentFu, Yes, as said above "_the pagination buttons is recreated each and every time the table is redrawn_", so if you want to insert elements this way, you must do it in `drawCallback()`.